# ipython3 - Almost every time I tab complete in ipython3 it runs %rehashx, is there a workaround?

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, ipython-magic

I've tried googling around but haven't found much / anything, the following also doesn't help at all...

https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html

typical usecase is:

```
In [31]: from sqlalch<TAB>  
Caching the list of root modules, please wait!
(This will only be done once - type '%rehashx' to reset cache!)

em
Caching the list of root modules, please wait!
(This will only be done once - type '%rehashx' to reset cache!)


Caching the list of root modules, please wait!
(This will only be done once - type '%rehashx' to reset cache!)


                        sqlalchemy
```

Also running `%rehashx` by itself also doesn't help. I also pip installed `pyreadline`.

Any ideas what is going wrong? Where does `%rehashx` store info?

**EDIT**

The output from `get_ipython().db['rootmodules_cache']` gives the following:

```
for key in d.keys(): print key
# /usr/local/bin
# /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
# /usr/lib/python3.5
# /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages <- should be in here
# /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload
# /usr/lib/python35.zip
# /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/extensions
# /usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
# /home/user/.ipython

import sqlalchemy
sqlalchemy.__file__
# /user/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/__init__.py
```

However sqlalchemy is not in the list

```
d = get_ipython().db['rootmodules_cache']
'sqlalchemy' in d['/user/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages']
# False
```

Comment: This suggests that the cache isn't working correctly. What do you get from `get_ipython().db['rootmodules_cache']`?

Comment: @ThomasK I edited the question, any insights from the updated question?

Comment: I think that suggests that that entry was already cached before you installed sqlalchemy. I don't think that should cause the 'Caching the list...' messages you see, though. Assuming you're using IPython 5, I bet this is something to do with prompt_toolkit doing completions in threads. Maybe it can be running that piece of code multiple times at once. Try running `%rehashx` , and then starting `import sqla<TAB>` and let it sit for ~2 minutes without typing anything else - maybe it will manage to cache things successfully then.

Comment: ok this worked - so far - no idea why. However `get_ipython().db['rootmodules_cache']` gives an error now

Comment: I just deleted the `.ipython/profile_default/db` folder and it created a new one and it seems to be working and is much faster... If it doesn't create problems in the future I'll probably just write that up as an answer...

Comment: Hmm, strange. I'm glad you got it working. Refactoring the completion machinery is in the plans for IPython 6.

Answer (score 0):

This command solved to me, in the Ipython:

```
!rm .ipython/profile_default/db/*
```

I hope it adds to yours.